# Flutter / Android: use Process.start and stdin

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to start a process which I want to interact with.

First approach:

```
Process p2 = await Process.start(name, []);
```

-> fails with an "Permission denied" Exception.

Second approach:

```
Process p2 = await Process.start(name, [], runInShell: true);
p2.stdin.writeln("uci");
```

-> Process gets created, but when trying to write to stdin, there is an error on stderr:

```
/bin/sh: /data/user/0/org.stonesoft.chess_partner/files/engine/stockfish: Permission denied
```

I would be grateful for any hint, how to get the process started and get the rights to access stdin...

Thanks and Best Regards,
Tobias